# Multiple tabs in UIWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I want to use UIWebView in my application.

I want to open up multiple URLs within the same UIWebView. Also, the tabs should be maintaining their own sessions.

Is this possible? If yes, can anyone please help me out with the same..

Comment: Tabs is not supported in UIWebView. Your best bet would be to create a custom implementation by storing the url addresses in an array, and using this as the datasource for a UICollectionView, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
But I am not sure that session of the URL is also maintain in UICollectionView.
Consider, HomeScreen contain multiple social networking site ,When I click on 1st tab open New window within UIWebView to load then coming  back and again open 2nd tab same UIWebView will respond to the same.
and also maintaining the session of first Tab also.

Comment: Hm I'm having trouble understanding your issue, can you make a mockup or something? As far as the url is concerned I would store the current webview's address and save it in the array when another tab is created. So then when you select a tab, it loads the url from the array at the tab's index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have find the the solutions on this,I have created the Home screen and TabViewController.When we click on the HomeScreen Menu ->Manually create a viewController with WebView inside and that viewController will be added to the TabViewController.TabViewController is AppDelegate instance. Next time it  will update the TabViewController.ViewControllers.

Comment: Here is the code to update 

`NSMutableArray *array =

(NSMutableArray*)appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers;
        
        ViewController2 *VC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];

        VC2.title = @"View2";

        VC2.urlString=self.urlString;

        [array addObject:VC2];

appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers =array;`